# React hooks useMemo, false as dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Recently I came across some weird usage of useMemo hook:

```
const memo = useMemo(callback, false);
```

As a second argument, instead of dependency is passed false.

Is this a valid code? React documentation states that dependency should be an array. What is the purpose of using false?

Comment: not valid if you use ts :D

Answer (score 8):

> Is this a valid code?

It depends on what you mean by `valid`.

- syntactically correct: **yes** (javascript, typescript)
- allowed by tools: **no** (eslint, flow, typescript)

Is it a valid call to React API? **no**.

While this code works today, passing `false` as dependency list is not mentioned in the documentation and the behaviour can change in any future react release.

In summary: update your code to `useMemo(callback, [])`.

Comment: Exactly that. That's **NOT** a valid React syntax and there are also warning messages about it. It should never be used this way just because it passes JS. I wonder how this Q/A got so many upvotes. +1 to your answer.

Comment: I feel that the answer to "Does it work?" could be better, perhaps more technical, or just  more meaningful for readers who are not the OP.

Comment: If you are looking for more info on why `false` works just as well as `[]`, this article on [Falsy and Truthy values in javascript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/falsy-values-in-javascript/) might be helpful. You'll come across many other instances of folks implementing this sort of logic in your JS career, so it's valuable to be aware of how these work.

Comment: @DimaTisnek, I was lost with your request to answer "Does it work?". Because the answer to this is in the question itself, and in the OP answer too. But you probably archived the desired result with your edit :) But I'd like to stress out that I purposely made it not neutral: never ever ever use quirks!

Comment: @Zachary, that's funny, my experience is quite opposite: never saw JS quirks in real life, except for this case. But I'd qualify it as a minor bug, not as "folks implementing this sort of logic"

Answer (score 4):

Actually I’ve analyzed react-reconsiler and it turnes out that above code is equivalent to this:

```
const memo = useMemo(callback, []);
```

That’s because of javascript quirks, where:

```
false.length = undefined;
false[1] = undefined;
```

So consequently:

```
undefined === undefined // true
```

Comment: Can you explain how you came up to the conclusion that `false` somehow equals to `[]`? Because reading the source code in `react-reconciler` [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/dd651df05e5802a31484f269b689c17acf087299/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.new.js#L1425), we can see that if it's not `undefined` (*nothing passed*) of `null`, it just compares the previous dependencies with the next dependencies, so if you even pass a string or a number, it will work as well; that doesn't mean this is valid syntax. Passing other than an array, `null`, or `undefined` is invalid.

Comment: @Mordechai even so passing an empty string or `true` or a number will have the same effect... That does not mean that this syntax is any close to corrent. It accepts an array or `null` or nothing (`undefined`).

Comment: This is an interesting discussion... On one hand, `false` is so much not an `Array`, but, on the other, JS code is built relying on JS quirks, so `for (let i = 0; i<{}.length; i++)` is a known no-op; But then e.g. `[...false]` is not... ‍♂️

Comment: @DimaTisnek, not relying, but despite of them. The only place for these quirks - obfuscation. And by the way `[...false]` at least at my console ;) throws

Comment: Tooling review: `typescript` doesn't like `false`, it says that type-wise it can be an array or `undefined`. Likewise, missing argument is not tolerated. Meanwhile `eslint` doesn't like explicit `undefined` because it can only analyse array literals for the exhaustive deps rule...

Comment: Tooling cont.: `flow` doesn't like `false` as it expects a "read-only array". Same issues with undefined and missing argument as above.